# Adding element to a scala set which is a map value

Tags: scala

I have the following map in Scala:

```
var m = Map[Int,Set[Int]]()
m += 1 -> Set(1)
m(1) += 2
```

I've discovered that the last line doesn't work. I get "error: reassignment to val".

So I tried

```
var s = m(1)
s += 2
```

Then when I compared `m(1)` with `s` after I added 2 to it, their contents were different. So how can I add an element to a set which is the value of a map?

I come from a Java/C++ background so what I tried seems natural to me, but apparently it's not in Scala.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably using `immutable.Map`. You need to use `mutable.Map`, or replace the set instead of modifying it with another immutable map.

Here's a reference of a description of the [mutable vs immutable data structures](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_1.html).

So...

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map
var m = Map[Int,Set[Int]]()
m += 1 -> Set(1)
m(1) += 2
```

Comment: Specifically, allocate your mutable map with the line: `collection.mutable.Map[Int, Set[Int]]()`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Stefan answer:
instead of using mutable Map, you can use mutable Set

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{Set => mSet}
var m = Map[Int,mSet[Int]]()
m += 1 -> mSet(1)
m(1)+=2
```

mSet is a shortcut to mutable Set introduced to reduce verbosity.

```
scala> m
res9: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]] = Map(1 -> Set(2, 1))
```

Comment: `import scala.collection._` gives you a more descriptive shortcut: `mutable.Set`

Answer (score 4):

I think what you really want here is a `MultiMap`

```
import collection.mutable.{Set, Map, HashMap, MultiMap}
val m = new HashMap[Int,Set[Int]] with MultiMap[Int, Int]
m.addBinding(1,1)
m.addBinding(1,2)
m.addBinding(2,3)
```

Note that `m` itself is a `val`, as it's the map itself which is now mutable, not the reference to the map

At this point, `m` will now be a:

```
Map(
  1 -> Set(1,2),
  2 -> Set(3)
)
```

Unfortunately, there's no immutable equivalent to MultiMap, and you *have* to specify the concrete subclass of `mutable.Map` that you'll use at construction time.

For all subsequent operations, it's enough to just pass the thing around typed as a `MultiMap[Int,Int]`