# Adding element to scala set which is a IMMUTABLE map

Tags: list, scala, set

I'm aware there is a similar question asked, but I can't figure out the solution to this problem ( Where I have an immutable map with an immutable set)

I have the following method, which aims to add an object of type Car to a set of Car objects. The case class with the Map is:

```
case class People( demo:Map[Person,Set[Car]] = Map() ) {
```

where every Car object has a name parameter of type person, and which has the following method that aims to add a car to the set of people, returning a new instance of People.

```
def +( c:Car ): People = {
```

The name variable in each car correlates to what Person the car should be mapped to. So c.name can be used to retrieve the key of where I should be adding the car. I.e.

```
var nameOfPerson  = c.name
demo(nameOfPerson) += c //Complains that += is not a member of Set
```

I've tried adding this car in a plethora of ways, including the solution brought up in this problem: [Adding element to a scala set which is a map value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149457/adding-element-to-a-scala-set-which-is-a-map-value)

But unfortunately, it keeps stating that value += is not a member of Set. I've also tried adding in as a parameter to the returned instance:

```
People(demo + (c.name, c))
```

But this keeps stating that (?,?) is required, pointing to c.name..

Any help is greatly appreciated

**P.S. I'm looking to append to the set if the mapping already exists, not overwrite it**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> People(demo + (c.name, c))`
> ```
>
> But this keeps stating that (?,?) is required, pointing to c.name..

The problem is with the signature of the `+` method on `Map`, it requires a tuple of key and value, but the parentheses are "eaten" as method call parentheses. The following should work:

```
People(demo + ((c.name, c)))
```

or

```
People(demo + (c.name -> c))
```

But instead of `c` you will have to have the new set. So:

```
case class People(demo: Map[Person,Set[Car]] = Map()) {
  def + (c: Car): People = {
    val oldSet = demo.getOrElse(c.name, Set.empty)
    val newSet = oldSet + c
    val newMap = demo + (c.name -> newSet)
    People(newMap)
  }
}
```